# Two NIC card with same mac address

Tags: networking, nic, mac-address

Yes its very strange but I have got two server having same H/W MAC address. 
The issue which I am facing is again very strange.

1st Server is normal windows server.
2nd Server is running KVM on Cenots. Have provisioned 4 Virtual Machine on this physical host.

**Issue:**

Windows server is accessible without any issue. 
Centos Physical Box is not accessible over ssh from remote location or over LAN connection. However I am able to connect to all 4 vms from remote location or over LAN. Also I have configured OpenVPN on one VM which works flawlessly.

I am looking for a solution how to access the Physical host now over LAN or from remote location.I have statically assigned IP to those two servers and avoided DHCP allocation of IP.

Nagios server sends multiple host down alert for Linux box only.Is there any way to get a solution for this without replacing the NIC card which will take time for me.

Currently I have enabled MAC address Spoofing but that is again a temporary solution.

PS: I am still pondering how the openvpn and other three VMs were operating without any issue whereas physical NIC card was always not reachable from anywhere.

Comment: `I am still pondering how the openvpn and other three VMs were
operating without any issue whereas physical NIC card was always not
reachable from anywhere.`

Because the virtual NICs inside the VMs use different mac addresses than the physical NIC.

Answer (score 12):

If your NICs have the same MAC addresses, you should stop fiddling around with workarounds and return them to the manufacturer as defective. Get proper replacements and continue on as normal. Incur the downtime *once* instead of the recurring issues that will pop up from continuing to hack together a "solution."

Comment: While sending a nastygram to the vendor is certainly justified, don't most NICs allow you to change the default MAC so that if you have any configuration dependent on it when you replace a card/server you only need to make the change in one place?

Comment: @DanNeely yes, but it's typically done in software from the host OS. Not something I want to rely on long-term.

Comment: Thanks all for your reply... I have made another arrangement for this which will give me hassle free time to concentrate on my other priority work for which I have posted this question. I have moved my windows box to another VLAN (since VLANs keep broadcasts local to the VLAN) which has solved the issue for me without spoofing the MAC address. I am not a networking expert but this worked for me. Replacing NIC is the final solution that I know but I was looking for some other help which can help me now at this moment.